# trying to install Polymer 2 CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, polymer, command-line-interface

I am trying to run a web app using Polymer. I recently installed Bower & Polymer CLI via Bower – however, whenever I attempt to run 'polymer serve' I receive the message '-bash: polymer: command not found' on Terminal.

Any tips on how I can get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the polymer-cli then create a project using polymer init, use polymer 3.0 app which use npm instead of bower the run polymer serve

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to an old version of `node`. I suggest you update `node`, as well as `npm` and `git`. Try installing `polymer-cli` again with the new node. Then you should be able to run `polymer` command.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the module is not installed or configured properly or an outdated version. Install or update the required module i.e, polymer-cli. After installing open new terminal or restart terminal and run polymer serve command.